# Can't find spreadsheet on GoogleDrive which was created by google_drive gem / learn-Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-apps-script

I'm trying to complete the learn-Rails tutorial and I have come across a problem implementing the writing of visitors recording in a GoogleDrive spreadsheet as depicted in the tutorial which actually refers to outdated procedures of loggging to the GoogleDrive spreadsheet.

Since userID / password aren't supported anymore I created a service account at Google as suggested by the google_drive gem docs and successfully connected from Rails to my spreadsheet this way:

```
def update_spreadsheet
    connection = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("SpreadSheet-acd8a78038a0.json")
    ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('Learn-Rails-Example')
    if ss.nil?
        ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('Learn-Rails-Example')
    end
    ws = ss.worksheets[0]
    last_row = 1 + ws.num_rows
    ws[last_row,1] = Time.new
    ws[last_row,2] = self.name
    ws[last_row,3] = self.email
    ws[last_row,4] = self.content
    puts "Current num rows: "+last_row.to_s
    ws.save
 end
```

Everythig runs fine in my Rails app but I can't access the spreadsheet from GoogleDrive in my Chrome browser despite the fact that the spreadsheet actually exists somewhere since I noticed num_rows increrements at console log each time I add a contact within the app.

If I can't see the spreadsheet directly in Google Drive from Chrome then it's bad news since I'd need to write a separete Ruby app to download the data.

Comment: At last I found the solution:

Comment: any chance you can enlighten us?

Comment: The problem was that the spreadsheet created by the account called by the google_drive gem in Rails could not be shared with my personal google account. I then made the opposite: I first created the spreadsheet under my google account, then I shared it with the google service I configured for the google_drive gem and eventually I could see the updated made by Rails to my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

At last I found the solution:

1. I created a Learn-Rails-Example spreadsheet (it was the name given by Rails) manually in my Google Drive
2. I shared that doc with the client_email of my service account (webserve@spreadsheet-61909.iam.gserviceaccount.com)
3. I Lunched the Rails app and noticed that from now on the spreadsheet was update and visible to Google Drive in Chrome browser.

Problem solved!